# BuddyPress: How to display multiple custom "single group (headers)" on a single page?

Tags: wordpress, loops, buddypress

The buddypress codex has a lot to say about the group directory (which doesn’t interest me atm all that much)
and about the different areas within a single group (which also doesn’t interest me atm).

But the page not linked on this overview (http://codex.buddypress.org/buddypress-components-and-features/groups) is the “single group” section itself.

Now, as the topic name already says, **the question is**:

> How to setup a single (normal WordPress) page with multiple custom single group headers (using Group Hierarchy: within a main group) without the user interaction part?

How would I pull this off?

I’m running the latest WP and BP versions. (At the time of writing this: 3.7.1 and 1.8.1).

Flashbytes

PS: This is a repost from http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-multiple-single-group-headers-on-a-single-page/ but the support forum at buddypress.org seems to be quite abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

http://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-multiple-single-group-headers-on-a-single-page/#post-174004

PS: the support forum at buddypress.org is by no means abandoned.
It is strictly volunteer - nobody has an obligation to answer your questions.